# How to typeset inclusion arrow?

Tags: symbols, arrows

I would like to know what is the best way to do an inclusion arrow, using xy or tikz. I know that there is a command for an arrow, like `\to`, for inclusions, but this is not expansible.

What do you use?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package gives you extansible hook-arrows which some authors use for inclusions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
A\xhookrightarrow{} B\qquad A\xhookrightarrow{f\circ g} B\qquad
A \xhookrightarrow[(f\circ g)\circ h]{} B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `\xrightarrow` from `amsmath` if you want an extensible "standard" arrow with super/subscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
A\rightarrow{} B\qquad A\xrightarrow{f\circ g} B\qquad
A \xrightarrow[(f\circ g)\circ h]{} B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]