# Inclusion arrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows

How can I give shape to some arrow in tikz, to draw the inclusion arrow?

I read a similar question [How to typeset inclusion arrow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66275/how-to-typeset-inclusion-arrow) with given answer, but the answer didn't really used TikZ, which I really need in order to produce nice large diagrams.

For instance, in this diagram (taken from  [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/labeled-chain/) ), I want, say, A to be included in A' :

```
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=3em]
{ 0 & A  & B  & C  & 0 \\
  0 & A' & B' & C' & 0 \\ };
 { [start chain] \chainin (m-1-1);
\chainin (m-1-2);
{ [start branch=A] \chainin (m-2-2)
    [join={node[right,labeled] {\eta_1}}];}
\chainin (m-1-3) [join={node[above,labeled] {\varphi}}];
{ [start branch=B] \chainin (m-2-3)
    [join={node[right,labeled] {\eta_2}}];}
\chainin (m-1-4) [join={node[above,labeled] {\psi}}];
{ [start branch=C] \chainin (m-2-4)
    [join={node[right,labeled] {\eta_3}}];}
\chainin (m-1-5); }
 { [start chain] \chainin (m-2-1);
\chainin (m-2-2);
\chainin (m-2-3) [join={node[above,labeled] {\varphi'}}];
\chainin (m-2-4) [join={node[above,labeled] {\psi'}}];
\chainin (m-2-5); }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For commutative diagrams I suggest using the [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package; it uses `TikZ` to facilitate the drawing of commutative diagrams (it has its own arrows library designed for diagrams and the arrow you are looking for is already buil-in); a little example with the requested inclusion (and some others just for illustration):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
0 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r} 
  & A\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}{\varphi}\arrow[hookrightarrow]{d}{\eta_1} 
  & B\arrow{r}{\psi}\arrow{d}{\eta_2} 
  & C\arrow{r}\arrow{d}{\eta_3} 
  & 0 \\
0 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r} 
  & A'\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}[swap]{\varphi'} 
  & B'\arrow{r}[swap]{\psi'} 
  & C'\arrow{r}
  & 0 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use the `arrows` library from `TikZ`, so for example, to use the `-latex` style from `TikZ`, you can say

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
commutative diagrams/.cd,
arrow style=tikz,
diagrams={>=latex}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzcd}
0 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r} 
  & A\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}{\varphi}\arrow[hookrightarrow]{d}{\eta_1} 
  & B\arrow{r}{\psi}\arrow{d}{\eta_2} 
  & C\arrow{r}\arrow{d}{\eta_3} 
  & 0 \\
0 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r} 
  & A'\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}[swap]{\varphi'} 
  & B'\arrow{r}[swap]{\psi'} 
  & C'\arrow{r}
  & 0 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above code changes the tip arrow style for all the diagrams, but you can select the -latex arrow tip just for some arrows (perhaps not really desirable to have two different arrow tips on the same diagram):

```
\arrow[hookrightarrow,-latex]{d}{\eta_1}
```

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes, the syntax is similar. Regarding the arrow tips, I updated my answer showing how to do it.

Answer (score 24):

You can use the `right hook-latex` , or `right hook->` arrow (depending on the arrow type you want on the other side) from the `arrows` library:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [ultra thick, right hook-latex, red] (0, 0) -- (3, 0);     
  \draw [ultra thick, right hook->,    blue] (0,-1) -- (3,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```