# hooked arrows with XY-matrix

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

The naive way to draw an hooked arrow in a diagram with XY-matrix is `\ar@{^{(}->}`. But it comes out that the hook is bigger respect the one of `\hookrightarrow`.

How can I fix this difference?

many thanks.

Comment: This TikZ-method might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68676/inclusion-arrow-in-tikz?

Comment: No way that I know with Xy-pic. The gigantic (and badly spaced) hook is one of the weaknesses of the package. Maybe a definition using low level graphics can be made, but my suggestion is to try `tikz-cd`, for commutative diagrams.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hooked arrow in `xy` is one of the ugly parts of this package. It just looks wrong. You could write this issue to the maintainer (if still active) or you switch to the more modern and much easier (to read) `tikz-cd`. In my MWE I am showing both in order to show the difference between their hooked arrows:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}    
\[\xymatrix{A\ar@{^{(}->}[r]& B}\]
\[\begin{tikzcd}        
    A \arrow[hook]{r} & B   
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The latter is equal to the 'normal' `\hookrightarrow`.